# Passing parameters from batch file to PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, batch-processing, powershell-4.0

I want to automate a task where I need to call a PowerShell script and pass few parameters to it (I am not the owner of that script, so I can't modify it). Is there any way I can pass parameters from batch file by calling that PowerShell script? Please find the below text when I tried to manually call the .ps1 file:

```
C:\Users\spa8\Desktop\V6_Git>git_powershell.bat

cmdlet New-MergeRequest.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
From_Branch: Xdev
To_Branch: master
Merge_Title: test
ADL_Issues[0]:
```

Here I am calling `git_powershell.bat` file which is calling `New-MergeRequest.ps1` file. Is there any way I can pass Xdev, master, etc. parameters in `git_powershell.bat` file so that `New-MergeRequest.ps1` can read it and execute it?

Comment: Using parameters in batch files: %0 and %9

Comment: Then call your script like `C:\Users\spa8\Desktop\V6_Git>git_powershell.bat Xdev` and read it like `%1`

Comment: Or %* to pass all the parameters without having to know how many there will be. Just be aware that %* sometimes gets wonky if there are special characters (like &) in the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You're prompted for input because the PowerShell script defined the parameters as [mandatory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-3.0), but was called without them. To avoid this you can simply pass the parameters as arguments to the PowerShell script, either as positional parameters:

```
New-MergeRequest.ps1 Xdev master "a test" ...
```

or named parameters:

```
New-MergeRequest.ps1 -From_Branch Xdev -To_Branch master -Merge_Title "a test" ...
```

If you don't want to hard-code the parameters in the batch file you need to pass [batch file parameters](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) to the PowerShell script, like this:

```
New-MergeRequest.ps1 "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" ...
```

or (if you want to pass all batch file arguments to the PowerShell script), like this:

```
New-MergeRequest.ps1 %*
```

and call the batch file like this:

```
git_powershell.bat Xdev master "a test" ...
```

Note that batch scripts support only positional parameters, not named parameters, so you must supply all arguments in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

In your .bat file:

```
powershell -File "file" %*
```

and call it like:

```
git_powershell.bat -Xdev arg1 -master uri
```